# C# UnitTests Mock File ReadAllBytes throws System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

In the controller i have an action result that returns a `FileStreamResult` object, before that the action uses the `byte[] ReadAllBytes(string path)` of the `File` class.

the action result:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string path)
{
    var myfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(myfile);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

in my xUnit test project i'm using Moq for setups.

the mock:

```
using IFileSystem = System.IO.Abstractions.IFileSystem;

private readonly Mock<IFileSystem> _fileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
```

the test method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Download_ShouldReturnPdfAsFileStreamResult_WhenIsFoundByPath()
{
    //Arrange
    var expected = new byte[]
    {
        68, 101, 109, 111, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 32, 99, 111, 110, 116,
        101, 110, 255, 253, 0, 43, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 109, 0, 101,
        0, 32, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116
    };

    var path = _fixture.Create<string>();

    _fileSystem.Setup(f => f.File.ReadAllBytes(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(expected);

    //Act
    var result = await _sutController.Download(path )
        .ConfigureAwait(false) as FileStreamResult;

    //Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
    //...
}
```

now when i run test i get this exception:

Message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\GF\Tests\GF.Web.Controllers.Tests\bin\Debug\net6.0\Path69bdc5aa-695a-4779-b38e-12cb2df4c21a'.

  Stack Trace: 
SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
OSFileStreamStrategy.ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
```

Comment: You are using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)` in `Download` method. You should use `IFileSystem.File.ReadAllBytes` instead.

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly, i changed also in my controller by injecting IFileSystem in the dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propoer way to do this as Alexander suggested in the comments is like this:

first start install the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions/ in the web and unit test project:

```
Install-Package System.IO.Abstractions
```

next inject the **IFileSystem** in the **Controller**

```
public class DownloadsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;

    public DownloadsController(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }
    ///Code ....
}
```

and of course **configure the dependency injection in the startup**

now in the **Controller ActionResult** use the `_fileSystem.File.ReadAllBytes(path)` instead of `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)`

Now in te test class just inject the **IFileSystem** Mock in the constuctor

```
using IFileSystem = System.IO.Abstractions.IFileSystem;
private readonly Mock<IFileSystem> _fileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();

public DownloadsControllerTests()
{
      _sutController = new DownloadsController(_fileSystem.Object);
}
```

And setup **_fileSystem.File.ReadAllBytes**:

```
_fileSystem.Setup(f => f.File.ReadAllBytes(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(expected).Verifiable();
```

expected is `new byte[]`

Comment: you are welcome to check it as answered

Comment: unfortunately in stackoverflow you can mark an answer as correct only if it's answerd by someone else (not the person who posted the question)

Comment: Ahha, you can mark it but it takes some time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate pure way to mock(Moq) with out adding any Nuget packages.
Implement an Interface and class.Then dependency inject the Interface.
Now you can mock in test class.

```
 public interface IMyHelper
  {
     byte[] ReadByteArrayFromFile(string path);
  }

  public class MyHelper:IMyHelper
 {
    public byte[] ReadByteArrayFromFile(string path)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return bytes; 
    }
 }

[TestClass]
      Mock<IMyHelper> myHelper = new Mock<IMyHelper>();
[TestInitialize]
   public void SetUp()
    {
         myHelper.Setup(x => x.ReadByteArrayFromFile(It.IsAny<string> 
        ())).Returns(new byte[123]);
    }
```